# Bind to a method with a parameter taken from current item in itemssource

Tags: c#, wpf, itemssource

I have a class that looks like the following, which I have many of which I wish to display in a table:

```
public class Score
{
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public float Points { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public List< Score > Scores { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
        Scores = new List< Score >();
    }

    public float GetScoreForDate( DateTime time )
    {
        foreach( Score score in Scores )
        {
            if( score.DateTime == time )
            {
                return score.Points;
            }
        }

        return 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Each row in the table is an instance of Player, and each column (after name and rank will be for each score).

I would somehow like to bind to the GetScoreForDate() and pass in the associated datetime value for the column to the current instance of Player that is being iterated over as the table goes through it's itemssource to populate the control.

I thought I might be able to use an [ObjectDataProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider(v=vs.110).aspx), but as far as I can tell, I can either call a static function, or a method on the same instance of Player (so every value displayed on the table is the same).

**Edit**
*Here's a sample implementation which shows how to bind each cell of the table to a single instance (when it should be whichever instance is associated with that row)*

```
ObjectDataProvider objectDataProvider = new ObjectDataProvider()
{
    ObjectInstance = player,
    MethodName = "GetScoreForDate"
};

objectDataProvider.MethodParameters.Add( score.DateTime );

Binding binding = new Binding()
{
    Source = objectDataProvider
};

TableViewColumn column = new TableViewColumn()
{
    Title = score.DateTime.ToShortDateString(),
    ContextBinding = binding
};
```

Comment: I am assuming you are binding from XAML. Can you show the XAML part?

Comment: You can only bind to properties, and not to methods. If you want to bind a button, then you should create a command and pass a parameter with it.

Comment: Actually I was binding from code behind (but I'm open to either)

Comment: @adminSoftDK That is not actually true. You can use an `ObjectDataProvider` To bind to a method